# JSON API - getting to internal objects to print to CSV

Tags: python, json

I'm pretty new to APIs and I'm working on retrieving two elements which are embedded in JSON.

```
r = requests.get(endpoint_url, headers=headers, params=params)
print(json.dumps(r.json(), indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

The clipped output I get is:

```
"complete_time": "2019-01-26T16:12:26.469749Z",
"data_deleted": false,
"document_folders": [],
"documents": [
    {
        "complete_time": "2019-01-26T16:09:30.567483Z",
        "document_folders": [],
        "document_type": "form",
        "exceptions": [],
        "id": 1,
        "layout_name": "FedEx_USA_Air_Bill",
        "layout_tags": [],
        "layout_uuid": "84f41017-d128-4cd4-9979-4985741e5681",
        "layout_version_name": "V2 (fixed date and lbs)",
        "layout_version_uuid": "27294ae3-17e5-40fd-a515-bdc7cc6a8a87",
        "pages": [
            {
                "corrected_image_url": "/api/v4/image/be167a88-9d1d-43bc-82b2-3d96d8c06656",
                "exceptions": [],
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "exceptions": [],
                        "field_definition_attributes": {
                            "consensus_required": false,
                            "data_type": "Account Number",
                            "multiline": false,
                            "required": false,
                            "supervision_override": null
                        },
                        "field_image_url": "/api/v4/image/be167a88-9d1d-43bc-82b2-3d96d8c06656?start_x=0.3110429607297866&start_y=0.1052441592299208&end_x=0.5696909842243418&end_y=0.16043316955780607",
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Sender Account Number",
                        "output_name": null,
                        "state": "complete",
                        "substate": null,
                        "transcription": {
                            "data_deleted": false,
                            "normalized": "168504411",
                            "raw": "1685-0441-1",
                            "row_index": null,
                            "source": "machine_transcription",
                            "user_transcribed": null
                        }
                    }
                ], <cut off>
```

I want to get to documents-->pages-->fields-->name and documents-->pages-->fields-->name-->transcription-->raw

If I use `result = json.loads(r.text)` I can only get to the top level keys (e.g. documents). I had thought erroneously that I could get to the sub-keys using:

```
print (result['documents']['pages']['fields']['name']
```

but that results in an error of `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`.

Is there any easy way to get to the sub-keys at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're lucky, the problem is simple.

A JSON file can really only contain 2 types of elements.

1. Dictionary
2. List

When you accede `result['documents']`, it makes sense, since result is a dictionary. However, `result['documents']` is a list (notice the '[' char). I don't know how many documents there is in this list (and the same problem applies to the "pages" element).

A simple solution would be to print all of them, like this:

```
for document in result['documents']:
    for page in document ["pages"]:
        for field in page["fields"]
            print(field["name"])
```

Answer (score 1):

You're misreading your json hierarhcy, `results['documents']` actually returns a list and not a dictionary.

The square bracket ([) right behind documents indicates this.

```
"documents": [
```

Same thing with `pages` and `fields`

try accessing `result['documents'][0]['pages'][0]['fields'][0]['name']` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Several of the nested values in the data structure are lists and must be indexed with an integer. Using `0` will access the first one.

Here's what I mean:

```
import json

json_str = '''\
{
    "complete_time": "2019-01-26T16:12:26.469749Z",
    "data_deleted": false,
    "document_folders": [],
    "documents": [
        {
            "complete_time": "2019-01-26T16:09:30.567483Z",
            "document_folders": [],
            "document_type": "form",
            "exceptions": [],
            "id": 1,
            "layout_name": "FedEx_USA_Air_Bill",
            "layout_tags": [],
            "layout_uuid": "84f41017-d128-4cd4-9979-4985741e5681",
            "layout_version_name": "V2 (fixed date and lbs)",
            "layout_version_uuid": "27294ae3-17e5-40fd-a515-bdc7cc6a8a87",
            "pages": [
                {
                    "corrected_image_url": "/api/v4/image/be167a88-9d1d-43bc-82b2-3d96d8c06656",
                    "exceptions": [],
                    "fields": [
                        {
                            "exceptions": [],
                            "field_definition_attributes": {
                                "consensus_required": false,
                                "data_type": "Account Number",
                                "multiline": false,
                                "required": false,
                                "supervision_override": null
                            },
                            "field_image_url": "/api/v4/image/be167a88-9d1d-43bc-82b2-3d96d8c06656?start_x=0.3110429607297866&start_y=0.1052441592299208&end_x=0.5696909842243418&end_y=0.16043316955780607",
                            "id": 1,
                            "name": "Sender Account Number",
                            "output_name": null,
                            "state": "complete",
                            "substate": null,
                            "transcription": {
                                "data_deleted": false,
                                "normalized": "168504411",
                                "raw": "1685-0441-1",
                                "row_index": null,
                                "source": "machine_transcription",
                                "user_transcribed": null
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
             ]
        }
    ]
}
'''

results = json.loads(json_str)

name = results['documents'] [0] ['pages'] [0] ['fields'] [0] ['name']
print(name)  # -> Sender Account Number
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out in the end, having realised I was dealing with arrays and not objects and therefore ended up with nested for loops.

```
for documents in result['documents']:
    for pages in documents['pages']:
        for fields in pages['fields']:
            print (fields['name'])
            print (fields['transcription']['raw'])
```